# Extracting multiple string to constant in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

In my code, there are a lot of strings appeared in the following structure:

```
map.put("string_1", value_1);
map.put("string_2", value_2);
// etc.
```

I would like to extract the string key to a constant. However, doing this one by one will take forever...So, is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea in Intellij, but if your lines are genuinely that simple, you can do it with a bit of command line fu:

```
grep map.put YourClass.java | awk -F\" '{print "public static final String " $2 " = \"" $2 "\";"}'
```

to get the string declarations:

```
public static final String string_1 = "string_1";
public static final String string_2 = "string_2";
```

Then

```
grep map.put YourClass.java | awk -F\" '{print $1 $2 $3}'
```

to replace the `map.put` lines.

```
map.put(string_1, value_1);
map.put(string_2, value_2);
```

Copy and paste from the command line into your file; or use a text editor which lets you do it inline (e.g. in Vim, <kbd>shift+V</kbd> to select the lines, then <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>!</kbd> and enter the awk command from above).

Comment: You can do this without leaving the IDE (any IDE: IntelliJ, Eclipse, Netbeans, etc.) with search/replace using a regular expression.

Comment: Of course you can. Silly of me not to think of that ;)

Comment: just use ctrl + alt + c

Answer (score 6):

Select the string and use Ctrl + Alt + C. All strings will be replaced with a constant.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ

- Go to preferences
- Search for 'keymap'
- Search for 'Introduce Constant'
- Save your desired shortcut key

In your code, select the string expression and press key shortcut